# Avoid Duplicate record across columns

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I Have a code that will determine if a data is already existing. The problem is, it is still adding even already exists.

Already tried some code that will add and not add if data exists

```
If txtHostname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill-up all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Inventory!")
        Else
            Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Asset WHERE Monitor1=@Monitor1 AND Monitor2=@Monitor2"
            Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(theQuery, con)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monitor1", txtMonitor1.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monitor2", txtMonitor2.Text)

            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    ' User already exists
                    MsgBox("User Already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
                Else
                    ' User does not exist, add them
                    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert into Asset ([Monitor1],[Monitor2]) values ('" + txtMonitor1.Text + "','" + txtMonitor2.Text + "')", con2)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Records Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add New Customer!")
                    txtMonitor1.Text = ""
                    txtMonitor2.Text = ""
                End If
            End Using

            con.Close()
        End If
```

It should be, when I search 1 data in column1 it should detect if data is already exists in column1 and column2. Not just in column1.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your Logic, because something won't add up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to **search** and return the **result** about whether **Fields exist or not** , you should not use **OledbReader**, also I did notice that `reader` doesn't `Read` (Even if it is not even correct to use it in this scenario). You could rather use `ExecuteScalar` and see if Fields exist or not (**>0 or <0**).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim CMDText As String = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Asset WHERE Monitor1=@Monitor1 AND Monitor2=@Monitor2")
        Dim Found As Integer
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHostname.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Please fill-up all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Inventory!")
        Else
            Using CN As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = "CON_STR"},
                           Cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(CMDText, CN)
                CN.Open()
                With Cmd1.Parameters
                    .Add("@Monitor1", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMonitor1.Text
                    .Add("@Monitor2", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMonitor2.Text
                End With
                Found = Cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
            End Using
            If Found > 0 Then
                ' User already exists
                MsgBox("User Already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
            Else
                Dim CmdText1 As String =
                   ("INSERT INTO Asset (Monitor1,Monitor2) VALUES (@Monitor1 ,@Monitor2)")
                Using Cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(CmdText1, CN)
                    With Cmd.Parameters
                        .Add("@Monitor1", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMonitor1.Text
                        .Add("@Monitor2", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMonitor2.Text
                    End With
                    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    ' User does not exist, add them
                    MsgBox("Records Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add New Customer!")
                    txtMonitor1.Text = String.Empty
                    txtMonitor2.Text = String.Empty
                    Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

In my example Code : "CON_STR" = My ConnectionString that I used to test my Code, as you did not provide any.